# How to set spark executor memory in the Azure Data Factory Linked service

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-data-factory, databricks, azure-databricks

My Spark Scala code is failing due to Spark out of memory issue. I am running the code from ADF pipeline. In Databricks cluster, the executor memory is set to 4g. I want to change this value at ADF level instead of changing it at cluster level. While creating a linked service we have additional cluster settings where we can define the cluster spark configuration. Please find the below. Could someone please let me know how to set the spark executor memory in linked service in ADF.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Name = spark.executor.memory` and `Value = 6g`

[image]

Monitor core configuration settings to ensure your Spark jobs run in a predictable and performant way. These settings help determine the best Spark cluster configuration for your particular workloads.

Also refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-settings

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this and the values are reflecting in the Spark UI. But the number of executors are 2 and I want to increase this number, can we do this in the same way as we increased the executor memory?